# iOS - Embedding Facebook video in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, video, uiwebview

In my app I have a `UIWebView` which shows content generated from WP (HTML code generated from Facebook embedding).
The content HTML is loaded with `loadHMTLString:baseURL:` method (where for base URL I use URL to mainBundle file path, because of a local CSS file). The videos I've tried and have problems with are set to Public visibility.

The **problem** I am facing is that when the content contains a **Facebook embedded video**, the video is not shown. Instead, in the place where it should be placed, there is a **blank space**.

I've had a similar problem showing an embedded post from Twitter, or Instangram (not the same kind of problem tho. Here, there was a post frame, but it was without a picture, or text). I have solved it by adding "http:" to the javascript file link. That solution doesn't work for facebook video problem.
Also, I've tried using `WKWebView`, without any luck. I have tried searching for a similar problem here, but I haven't found one.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried "https" instead?

Comment: Yes, no luck there either.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the UIWebveiw using Safari to see if you get any errors?

Comment: No, but I've found a workaround by placing the video in an iframe. But still i'm not completely sure why the post generated embed doesn't work.

Comment: @NikolaJolić could you post the workaround your came up with?

Comment: @ken4z I'm no longer working on this app, so I can't post the code, but placing the embedded post in an iframe in html code helped. It is still used like that. The only problem with that solution is that the iframe itself is loaded after everyhing else in the web view.

Answer (score 1):

> where for base URL I use URL to mainBundle file path

HTML documents which include the Facebook Javascript SDK do not execute that SDK properly within a UIWebView, unless the baseURL parameter is set to an external website.

That is,

```
someUIWebView.loadHTMLString(HTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

Will not work.  But

```
someUIWebView.loadHTMLString(HTMLString, baseURL: URL(string: "https://google.com/"))
```

WILL work, even if your site has nothing to do with google.com.

It appears to me that the Facebook SDK isn't happy with a nil or local/file URL; it needs a genuine `HTTP` URL.